# how to trigger focus event on a specific element in angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a input field that gets updated automatically and I want to trigger focus event immediately. How can i achieve this?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="point" [(ngModel)]="point" placeholder="point" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="1" placeholder="Point Explaination"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

The point **point** input is updated when clicking on a point in google map. I need to focus on the next input (description) immediately to insert description.

Comment: Use @ChildView() to get access to your HTML Element in you class. You will be able to trigger .focus() on it

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Hrishikesh, I also got a simpler way to do it instead of injecting ElementRef:

Added the tag `#description` to the input:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="description" #description rows="1" placeholder="Point Explaination"></textarea>
```

Declared a variable in the component:

```
@ViewChild('description') description;
```

And Finally ***where required***:

```
this.description.nativeElement.focus();
```

Comment: this is great though I tried to explain it little more :D

Answer (score 1):

so check first if you first input in empty or no like

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="point" [(ngModel)]="point" (ngModelChange)="textAreaEmpty()" placeholder="point" />
    </div>
```

In ts file

```
point: string = '';

textAreaEmpty(){
  if (this.point != '') {
    console.log(this.point);
  }
}
```

set a variable in other input like

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <textarea  #myInput class="form-control" name="description" rows="1" placeholder="Point Explaination"></textarea>
    </div>
```

and in ts file

```
@ViewChild("myInput") inputEl: ElementRef;

  focusInput() {
    this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus()
  }
```

and call this function while checking the value in empty or not.

```
textAreaEmpty(){
      if (this.point != '') {
        console.log(this.point);
this.focusInput();
      }
    }
```